# IE 8 HTML1113 issue causing application to log out

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I keep getting thrown to the login screen of my application in IE 8 when i open a link in a new window .

This is the error message that keeps coming in the Dev tool bar

HTML1113: Document mode restart from Quirks to IE9 Standards

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Try this one:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-to-fix-ie-looping-in-quirks-mode-html1113/1ab9a2bb-5d85-4986-81c4-6de4799e4840